# multiply several tables in big one

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

There is a task about sql.
I have tree tables

Table_1

```
Id Name
1  Name1
2  Name2
```

Table_2

```
Id Name
3  Name3
4  Name4
```

And final table
Table_3

```
Id Table1_Id  Table2_Id Value
1   1         3         Some Text
2   1         4         Some another text
```

So i would like two more rows to be generated for table_3

```
Id   Table1_Id  Table2_Id Value
1    1         3         Some Text
2    1         4         Some another text
null 2         3         null
null 2         4         null
```

How can i do this ?
In fact, i have more then 5 tables with same signature as Table_1 and Table_2.
And each time i add one row to the one of this table, the result Table_3's values count should be multiplied.

Answer (score 0):

Is `Table_3` created from a `JOIN` of `Table_1` and `Table_2`?

If so what `JOIN` are you using?

Have you tried `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER JOIN`?